# GEtting address in CMS block

Tags: module, cms, customer-account

I have the customer activation module https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation
on my site the email notification template calls `{{var customer.getEmail()}}` I would like to also get the company name

is there a way to do that i basically need to call

```
 Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load()->getCompany({{var customer.getDefaultBilling()}});
```

in the template is there a way to do this?
Thanks

as in

```
2016-02-12T18:09:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Mage_Customer_Model_Address Object
        (
            ...
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    ...
                    [company] => mycompany
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
{{var customer.getDefaultBilling().getCompany()}}
```

I'm not exactly sure how the parsing of the template params is done but since the whole customer object is passed in this might work

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php#L607

**===UPDATE===**

although I did not yet understand this completely, this function is responsible for calling the methods on and getting attributes of an object var in the E-Mail template and it does look like it's able to chain the functions:

https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php#L292

Comment: thanks for looking into this `var customer.getAddresses()` returns an object with the customers address info

Comment: i edited the question to include the array that is returned